# What might be preventing an iOS user from saving an image?

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm currently using a lightbox plugin called Simple Lightbox and I'm encountering some issues. Right click > save as is not disabled on Chrome, but pressing and holding an image in the lightbox does not result in the option to save it on iOS devices. I was wondering if there are any javascript or css properties that I could look for in the code that might be preventing this action from occuring.

simple lightbox: http://simplelightbox.com/

github link: https://github.com/andreknieriem/simplelightbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer right after posting! I'll leave it here in case anyone stumbles upon this later.

In //touchcontrols on simple-lightbox.js, I deleted the following:

```
> `swipeStart    = 0,
                swipeEnd     = 0,
                swipeYStart = 0,
                swipeYEnd = 0,
                mousedown = false,
```

I also disabled swiping to change photos. I hope this helps someone later on!